# Highcharts error number 17 when plotting map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I am new in using *Highcharts* to create a map. In this case I have data which has ****village name, latitude, longitude, crop yield difference and predicted practice***. my intention is when a user select ***village name*** on ***selectbox***,a marker should appear on the map using ***longitude and latitude data*** to show the location of the village, at that point also show **predicted practice**.

I have written my code but I get this error every time I select ***village name*** from the select box

```
2react-dom.development.js:22839 Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
    at c.Chart.e (highcharts.src.js:462:1)
    at c.fireEvent (highcharts.src.js:2407:1)
    at c.error (highcharts.src.js:470:1)
    at c.Chart.initSeries (highcharts.src.js:23590:1)
    at highcharts.src.js:25127:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c.Chart.firstRender (highcharts.src.js:25124:1)
    at c.Chart.<anonymous> (highcharts.src.js:23572:1)
    at c.fireEvent (highcharts.src.js:2407:1)
    at c.Chart.init (highcharts.src.js:23446:1)
2react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef> component:

    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6112:33
    at MapChart (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:132:5)
    at div
    at div
    at VillagePredictions (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:166:96)
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
react-dom.development.js:12056 Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
    at c.Chart.e (highcharts.src.js:462:1)
    at c.fireEvent (highcharts.src.js:2407:1)
    at c.error (highcharts.src.js:470:1)
    at c.Chart.initSeries (highcharts.src.js:23590:1)
    at highcharts.src.js:25127:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at c.Chart.firstRender (highcharts.src.js:25124:1)
    at c.Chart.<anonymous> (highcharts.src.js:23572:1)
    at c.fireEvent (highcharts.src.js:2407:1)
    at c.Chart.init (highcharts.src.js:23446:1)
```

Being new to Highcharts I have searched for solutions but havent figure it out.

Here is the code that is supposed to work

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import axios from 'axios';


const MapChart = ({ lat, lon }) => {
  const options = {
    chart: {
      map: 'countries/tz/tz-all',
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Tanzania Map',
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Villages',
        type: 'mapbubble',
        data: [
          {
            name: 'Selected Village',
            z: 1,
            lat: lat,
            lon: lon,
          },
        ],
        maxSize: '12%',
      },
    ],
  };

  return <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />;
};

const VillagePredictions = () => {
  const [selectedVillage, setSelectedVillage] = useState(null);
  const [villages, setVillages] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get('village_pred/')
      .then(response => {
        setVillages(response.data.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  const options = villages.map(village => ({
    value: village.name,
    label: village.name,
  }));

  const handleVillageChange = selectedOption => {
    setSelectedVillage(selectedOption);
  };

  const selectedVillageData =
    selectedVillage !== null
      ? villages.find(village => village.name === selectedVillage.value)
      : null;
console.log(selectedVillageData)

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Village Predictions</h2>
      <div style={{ width: '200px', marginBottom: '20px' }}>
        <Select
          value={selectedVillage}
          onChange={handleVillageChange}
          options={options}
        />
      </div>
      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {!loading && selectedVillageData && (
        <div>
          <p>Selected Village: {selectedVillage.label}</p>
          <MapChart
            lat={selectedVillageData.latitude}
            lon={selectedVillageData.longitude}
          />
          <p>Crop Yield Difference: {selectedVillageData.crop_yield_difference}</p>
          <p>Predicted Farm Practice: {selectedVillageData.predicted_practice}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default VillagePredictions;
```

Now when I print my data on the console, this is how data for a single village looks like

```
altitude : 1591.4000244140625
crop_yield_difference: 0.4101111111111102
latitude : -4.2583160400390625
longitude: 35.52566146850586
name: "Seloto"
predicted_practice: "fertilizer"
```

And finally my react version is **"react": "^18.2.0"**, and highcharts is **"highcharts": "^7.2.0",**

Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce this to be used as an example but anyone who has experienced this to help will really save my day. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts error #17 results from the fact that you have used `Highcharts` which doesn't have `mapbubble` series type. You should use Highmaps and `mapChart` constructor type. For example:

```
import Highmaps from "highcharts/highmaps";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

const MapChart = ({ lat, lon }) => {
  const options = useMemo(() => ({
    chart: {
      map: 'countries/tz/tz-all'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Tanzania Map'
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Villages',
        type: 'mapbubble',
        data: [
          {
            name: 'Selected Village',
            z: 1,
            lat: lat,
            lon: lon
          },
        ],
        maxSize: '12%'
      }
    ]
  }), [lat, lon]);

  return <HighchartsReact constructorType="mapChart" highcharts={Highmaps} options={options} />;
};
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-4g96sc?file=/demo.jsx

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started